# Django templates: False vs. None

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement

How can I distinguish between `None` and `False` in django templates?

```
{% if x %}
True 
{% else %}
None and False - how can I split this case?
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every Django template context [contains `True`, `False` and `None`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#builtin-variables]). For Django 1.10 and later, you can do the following:

```
{% if x %}
True 
{% elif x is None %}
None
{% else %}
False (or empty string, empty list etc)
{% endif %}
```

Django 1.9 and earlier do not support the `is` operator in the `if` tag. Most of the time, it is ok to use `{% if x == None %}` instead.

```
{% if x %}
True 
{% elif x == None %}
None
{% else %}
False (or empty string, empty list etc)
{% endif %}
```

With Django 1.4 and earlier, you do not have access to `True`, `False` and `None` in the template context, You can use the [`yesno`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter instead.

In the view:

```
x = True
y = False
z = None
```

In the template:

```
{{ x|yesno:"true,false,none" }}
{{ y|yesno:"true,false,none" }}    
{{ z|yesno:"true,false,none" }}
```

Result:

```
true
false
none
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom filter:

```
@register.filter
def is_not_None(val):
    return val is not None
```

then use it:

```
{% if x|is_not_None %}
    {% if x %}
        True
    {% else %}
        False
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    None
{% endif %}
```

Of course, you could tweak the filter to test whatever condition you like also...

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you shouldn't have to do this -- it should be built-in to Django!

Answer (score 3):

An enhancement of the previous answers could be:

```
{% if x|yesno:"2,1," %}
   # will enter here if x is True or False, but not None
{% else %}
   # will enter only if x is None
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nice use of what's already available in the template language.

Comment: I find this confusing -- it is not at all obvious that you are trying to distinguish between None and False.  Even now I don't really get how it works.

Comment: @NickPerkins, you will get it once you know that the third parameter in the `yesno` filter is returned if `x` is None.

Answer (score 0):

Create context_processor (or use from the [django-misc](https://github.com/ilblackdragon/django-misc) module `misc.context_processors.useful_constants`) with `True`, `False`, `None` constants and use `{% if x == None %}` or `{% if x == False %}`

`context_processor.py`:

```
def useful_constants(request):
    return {'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tricky way:

```
{% if not x.denominator %}
    None
{% else %}
    {% if x %}
        True
    {% else %}
        False
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

That's because "None" doesn't have the attribute "denominator", while it is 1 for both "True" and "False".